# PGFplots library SmithChart and Colorbrewer incompatible?

Tags: pgfplots, color, tikzlibrary

**What I want:** Using Colorbrewer in a Smith Chart

**What I have:** I can use regular colors like red, green, and blue, but a specified colorbrewer scheme does not seem to work.

**What I tried:** I used the colorbrewer library before, so I have some working pictures with rectangular plots but for a smith chart it does not seem to work, or I might still have errors in my code.

an MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Set1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cycle list name=Set1,]
\begin{smithchart}[
%   cycle multi list={Set1-4}, % different (kinda desperate) approaches
    colormap name={Set1},
%   cycle list name=Set1, % my regular setting
]   
\draw[] (0,1) --(1,0);
\end{smithchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:** solved:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Set1-4}
%% data of file.txt
%freq   S(1,1)
%5.00000000000000000E5  -9.92135364814345170E-1    1.25169556541143370E-1 
%6.66760716082158390E5  -9.86057152455524030E-1    1.66407007338343950E-1
%8.89139705020784810E5  -9.75339522033835850E-1    2.20709802135765590E-1 
%1.18568685283347500E6  -9.56563611495252180E-1    2.91523681993693450E-1
%1.58113883008889690E6  -9.24041871507889740E-1    3.82291275992791050E-1 
%2.10848251715075730E6  -8.68803182091356160E-1    4.95157581773654790E-1
%2.81170662596430130E6  -7.78027937536712070E-1    6.28229678073529390E-1
%3.74947104668181290E6  -6.36656581449933690E-1    7.71147454963370830E-1
%5.00000000000000000E6  -4.33913600649795580E-1    9.00954486736777050E-1
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{smithchart}[
    ]
    \addplot+[
    is smithchart cs,
    index of colormap=4 of Set1-4, 
    ] table[
    skip first n=1, 
    meta index=0, 
    x expr={\thisrowno{1}}, 
    y expr={\thisrowno{2}}
    ] {file.txt};
    \end{smithchart}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So far you didn't have an `\addplot` added to you plot. If you do so, you will see that it works perfectly. Or where do you expect that the scheme should be used at your given example? (And delete the optional argument to the `tikzpicture` environment, which is currently causing an error.)

Comment: @StefanPinnow Originally, I had included`\addplot` (just as [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357618/avoid-clipped-line-decoration-on-y-axis) ) and just shortened it for the MWE, but with your confirmation that it _should_ work, I cross-checked again with [this older question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350030/specify-brewer-color-in-addplot) and found that the problem was concerning the difference between `\addplot[...]` and `\addplot+[...]`.
(Any links to information on the difference between these two would be appreciated)

Comment: In short: (pure) `\addplot` using the current cycle list element. When you use `\addplot [...]` then *only* the given `...` options are used (and thus not the cycle list element. And when you use `\addplot+ [...]` then the `...` options are *appended* to the current cycle list element options.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.